# Find and replace in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script with various file paths in it. e.g /home/kevin/Downloads.

What I want to do is prompt a person for their username and replace all instances of 'kevin' with their name.

```
# echo Please enter your username: case sensitive

# read var1
```

So how do I replace all instances of 'kevin' with var1? Thanks!

Comment: You could use `$HOME` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SED command to find and replace strings in a file.
Give this a try:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Please enter your username: case sensitive
read var1
sed -i -e "s/kevin/${var1}/g" /path/to/file_name_with_paths.sh
```

I hope it helps.